# Go goroutine with channel strange result

Tags: go, goroutine

When i run the goroutines, i generally get 40 as value, i know its about the concurrency but why is the last number coming? I suppose the output must be:

```
Page number:  34  
Page number:  12  
Page number:  8  
Page number:  2  
Page number:  29
```

**example source code**:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func getWebPageContent(url string, c chan int, val int) interface{} {

    if r, err := http.Get(url); err == nil {
        defer r.Body.Close()
        if body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body); err == nil {
            c <- val
            return string(body)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return "XoX"

}

const MAX_TH = 40

func main() {

    // pln := fmt.Println
    messages := make(chan int)
    for j := 0; j < MAX_TH; j++ {
        go func() { getWebPageContent("http://www.example.com", messages, j) }()
    }

    routine_count := 0
    var page_number int
    for {
        page_number = <-messages
        routine_count++
        fmt.Println("Page number: ", page_number)
        if routine_count == MAX_TH {
            break
        }
    }
    close(messages)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Go Programming Language
>
> [Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://golang.org/doc/faq)
>
> [What happens with closures running as goroutines?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)
>
> Some confusion may arise when using closures with concurrency.
>   Consider the following program:
>
> ```
> func main() {
>     done := make(chan bool)
>
>     values := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
>     for _, v := range values {
>         go func() {
>             fmt.Println(v)
>             done <- true
>         }()
>     }
>
>     // wait for all goroutines to complete before exiting
>     for _ = range values {
>         <-done
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> One might mistakenly expect to see a, b, c as the output. What you'll
>   probably see instead is c, c, c. This is because each iteration of the
>   loop uses the same instance of the variable v, so each closure shares
>   that single variable. When the closure runs, it prints the value of v
>   at the time fmt.Println is executed, but v may have been modified
>   since the goroutine was launched. To help detect this and other
>   problems before they happen, run go vet.
>
> To bind the current value of v to each closure as it is launched, one
>   must modify the inner loop to create a new variable each iteration.
>   One way is to pass the variable as an argument to the closure:
>
> ```
> for _, v := range values {
>     go func(u string) {
>         fmt.Println(u)
>         done <- true
>     }(v)
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, the value of v is passed as an argument to the
>   anonymous function. That value is then accessible inside the function
>   as the variable u.
>
> Even easier is just to create a new variable, using a declaration
>   style that may seem odd but works fine in Go:
>
> ```
> for _, v := range values {
>     v := v // create a new 'v'.
>     go func() {
>         fmt.Println(v)
>         done <- true
>     }()
> }
> ```

Therefore, in your case, create a new variable by adding the statement `j := j`,

```
for j := 0; j < MAX_TH; j++ {
    j := j
    go func() { getWebPageContent("http://www.example.com", messages, j) }()
}
```

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func getWebPageContent(url string, c chan int, val int) interface{} {
    if r, err := http.Get(url); err == nil {
        defer r.Body.Close()
        if body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body); err == nil {
            c <- val
            return string(body)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return "XoX"
}

const MAX_TH = 40

func main() {

    // pln := fmt.Println
    messages := make(chan int)
    for j := 0; j < MAX_TH; j++ {
        j := j
        go func() { getWebPageContent("http://www.example.com", messages, j) }()
    }

    routine_count := 0
    var page_number int
    for {
        page_number = <-messages
        routine_count++
        fmt.Println("Page number: ", page_number)
        if routine_count == MAX_TH {
            break
        }
    }
    close(messages)
}
```

Output:

```
Page number:  23
Page number:  6
Page number:  1
Page number:  3
Page number:  28
Page number:  32
Page number:  18
Page number:  22
Page number:  0
Page number:  36
Page number:  7
Page number:  21
Page number:  12
Page number:  2
Page number:  5
Page number:  4
Page number:  33
Page number:  13
Page number:  20
Page number:  27
Page number:  29
Page number:  8
Page number:  31
Page number:  10
Page number:  17
Page number:  25
Page number:  19
Page number:  35
Page number:  14
Page number:  38
Page number:  15
Page number:  30
Page number:  37
Page number:  39
Page number:  26
Page number:  9
Page number:  16
Page number:  11
Page number:  24
Page number:  34
```

Answer (score 1):

My first golang reply, may be completely off :-)

The loop could probably look like this:

```
...
for j := 0; j < MAX_TH; j++ {
    go func(x) { getWebPageContent("http://www.example.com", messages, x) }(j)
}
...
```

Basically, you define an anonymous function and call it with a parameter. You could do it differently but this solution looks very functional and sleek :-)

Comment: You should have read my answer. The answer you posted is in the FAQ that I posted: "To bind the current value of v to each closure as it is launched, one must modify the inner loop to create a new variable each iteration. One way is to pass the variable as an argument to the closure." The example is the second code fragment in the FAQ.

Comment: So your answer needs a 'tl;dr' section then :-)